# How to detected if signalR connection was closed deliberately?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to detect whenever the signalR connection was lost because of network issues or deliberately. I see a lot of solutions but they seem to be for an older version of Aspnet core signalR. (They use ondisconnected with the parameter stopcalled). In my version I only have the ondisconnectedasync with the parameter Exception exception which is always null.

I'm using the version 2.4.1 of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core in the server side. and "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4" in the client side.

This is my code:

```
public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {


            var httpContext = Context.GetHttpContext();
            //get the user that lost connection or is being disconnected.
            var user = users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);

            if(user != null && /* if connection was closed deliberately*/ )
            {
                //remove user from the list
                users.Remove(user);

                //log the user out.
                ParticipantController.Logout(user.UserId);
            }

            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
```

Does someone know how to achieve this functionality?
I want to know aswell if refreshing the page also counts as deliberate disconnection and if it does how can I distinguish it from an actual tab closed or windows closed disconnection.

Comment: When it is a connection issue, is the exception still null?

Comment: Yes, when refreshing, closing or network turned off. It doesn't matter what the reason is. It's always null.

Comment: You are using the wrong version of Singalr. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Comment: Ok but that is in the client side. Does that affect the server side aswell? And how? @StPaulis

Comment: Some years ago, `aspnet/signalr` changed to `microsoft/signalr` and It keeps the same version as the Core package of **ASP**. If you stack on the old one you miss some great features as the `automatic reconnection` and maybe there are some vulnerabilities. Maybe it fix your problem as well, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug/deficiency in Signalr for .NET Core. It's being tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26701.